# Criar DLL à partir de arquivos

Tags: lua, dll

Tenho alguns arquivos `.lua` com funções e gostaria de criar uma DLL com todos os arquivos, é possível?

Comment: É isto que deseja? http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua

Comment: Não achei como criar dll, só como compilar para .exe.

Comment: Tem certeza? Eu não li tudo mas tem 83 referências à DLL e pelo pouco que li parece indicar isso sim. Se não for, espero que alguém tenha uma informação melhor.

Comment: Eu vi apenas procedimentos para compilar o lua.h, que seria a dll Lua5.1.dll descompilada, creio eu.